# Generate different date for each iteration

Tags: java

Here needed to generate different values for Date in each iteration of for loop.

Using currentTimeMillis does not help as it gives same time but nanoTime gives wrong date altogether.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(new Date(System.nanoTime()));
    }
```

---

```
Mon Oct 30 19:33:43 IST 2017
Mon Oct 30 19:33:43 IST 2017
Mon Oct 30 19:33:43 IST 2017
Mon Oct 30 19:33:43 IST 2017
Mon Oct 30 19:33:43 IST 2017
Mon Oct 30 19:33:43 IST 2017
Mon Oct 30 19:33:43 IST 2017
Mon Oct 30 19:33:43 IST 2017
Mon Oct 30 19:33:43 IST 2017
Mon Oct 30 19:33:43 IST 2017
```

---

```
Tue Feb 09 09:56:54 IST 2292
Tue Feb 09 09:57:39 IST 2292
Tue Feb 09 09:58:10 IST 2292
Tue Feb 09 09:58:50 IST 2292
Tue Feb 09 09:59:24 IST 2292
Tue Feb 09 09:59:53 IST 2292
Tue Feb 09 10:00:29 IST 2292
Tue Feb 09 10:00:59 IST 2292
Tue Feb 09 10:01:37 IST 2292
Tue Feb 09 10:02:18 IST 2292
```

**UPDATE** : Need to generate different timestamp for each iteration as that is going in cassandra database where different records need to have unique timestamp. Otherwise they will overwrite each other. Also time should not be fake as adding a second in for loop would solve the problem but is fake time.Adding sleep is unfortunately not an option as the code needs to add records as fast as possible and exit

Comment: Why don't you print milliseconds in the first example using System.currentTimeMillis() ? the dates might not be the same

Comment: The first for loop iterates too quickly. Since there is not a significant enough time between each iteration, you will get the same time. Let it run for more than a second and you should see the time change slightly.

Comment: So, there is no requirement of how those dates are defined except that they are different? Having Dates in the year 3000 would be okay to? What exactly are you trying to archieve here?

Comment: you can add a wait for 1 second after each iteration so the date would change. simply add a `Thread.sleep(1000)` inside the loop

Comment: If you are using java 8, please consider using java.time API instead of Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only requirement is that the dates are different from each other, then you can just manually increment the date by an arbitrary amount in the loop.

And in case you're using Java 8 or higher, I also recommend staying clear of the old `java.util.Date` API and start using `java.time` instead.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    System.out.println( instant.toString() );
    // Choose whatever interval size you need in your specific case.
    instant = instant.plus( 1, ChronoUnit.MILLIS );
}
```

You can still convert back to Date objects if you really need to by using `Date.from( instant )`.

EDIT: Seeing your updated requirements, I adjusted my answer now.

There are several limitations that you need to be aware of:

- **System clock resolution**:
  You won't get around manually faking some dates (for example by adding a millisecond each iteration in the loop), since the resolution of the system clock is not precise enough to generate a distinct timestamp on each call.
- **Datatype of the column in your database**:
  Databases often only have a limited precision for the date values they can store. For example Oracle's old `Date` datatype can only store precision up to seconds and no fractions. I believe MS SQLServer's `DateTime` type rounds its milliseconds to the nearest third of a second or something like that.
- **Java datatype precision**:
  The old `java.util.Date` type can only store up to millisecond precision. `java.time.Instant` can also store nanoseconds. JDBC in Java 8 comes with matching methods that accepts `Instant` instead of `Date`, but the actual database and its JDBC driver implementation of course need to actually support that precision as well.

Answer (score 4):

To start with note that nano gives more value than milli and you are passing a nanoseconds value in place of milliseconds, hence the bizarre result.

What [Date(long date)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date(long)) constructor expecting

> date - the milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

What nanoTime returning

> Returns the current value of the running Java Virtual Machine's high-resolution time source, in nanoseconds.

The [nanoTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) is not at all related to Date(). It is designed and implemented to solve a different purpose.

> This method can only be used to measure elapsed time and **is not related to any other notion of system or wall-clock time**. The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative). The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to use a different origin.

---

> Here needed to generate different values for Date in each iteration of for loop.

Probably you can try adding time in minutes/days to the current date by adding *i* value ?

Answer (score 2):

The first code snippet is working as expected. All steps in the loop a executed at the same time. If you want different time then `sleep` the executing thread:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

which would give following:

```
Mon Oct 30 10:10:10 EDT 2017
Mon Oct 30 10:10:11 EDT 2017
Mon Oct 30 10:10:12 EDT 2017
Mon Oct 30 10:10:13 EDT 2017
Mon Oct 30 10:10:14 EDT 2017
Mon Oct 30 10:10:15 EDT 2017
Mon Oct 30 10:10:16 EDT 2017
Mon Oct 30 10:10:17 EDT 2017
Mon Oct 30 10:10:18 EDT 2017
Mon Oct 30 10:10:19 EDT 2017
```

The second code snippet is wrong in terms that Date is expecting millis in  constructor. The `nanoTime()` actually should be used to get the delta, as

> The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary time (perhaps in the future, so values may be negative).

Answer (score 0):

`new Date(long time)` [gives a date based on milliseconds](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date-long-) - it isn't that it's giving the wrong date, it's the correct date for the wrong time given

`System.currentTimeMillis()` gives the correct time for date, while `System.nanoTime()` is about 1000x the correct time (in milliseconds)

It may be easier to use `new Date()` over `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())`, [as they will both give the current time to the closest millisecond](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date--)

---

If your goal is to get similar dates, instead try incrementing the time you're initializing the dates with (in this case 1 second differences)

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    System.out.println(new Date(now + i * 1000));
```

Comment: The primary issue is that the output only shows whole seconds, not milliseconds.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Are you sure OP is using a computer slow enough that a for loop is taking multiple milliseconds?